FatalError: error TS6046: Argument for option '-moduleResolution' must be: 'node', 'classic', 'node16', 'nodenext'
I'm creating a vite react.js web application using typescript and tailwind CSS. I run tsc --watch on my command line and I'm getting the following errors:
tsconfig.json:3:25 - error TS6046: The argument to the '--moduleResolution' option must be: 'node', 'classic', 'node12', 'nodenext'.

tsconfig.json:8:5 - error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'allowImportingTsExtensions'.

tsconfig.json:21:5 - error TS5070: Option '--resolveJsonModule' cannot be specified without module resolution strategy 'node'.

My typescript version is: 5.6.2
Node: 20.13.0
My tsconfig.json looks like this:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "module": "es2020",
    "composite": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "ESNext",
      "ES2020",
      "DOM.Iterable"
    ],
    "types": [
      "vite/client",
      "jest"
    ],
    /* Bundler mode */
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "./dist"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/*.tsx",
    "./src/__tests__/**/*.ts",
    "./src/__tests__/**/*.tsx"
  ]
}


npm install typescript@latest;
Delete the node_modules folder and package-lock.json, followed by npm install



tsconfig.json:3:25 - error TS6046: The argument to the '--moduleResolution' option must be: 'node', 'classic', 'node12', 'nodenext'.

The error message tells you that bundler is not supported.

tsconfig.json:21:5 - error TS5070: Option '--resolveJsonModule' cannot be specified without module resolution strategy 'node'.

The third error message tells you to set your moduleResolution to node for it to work.
Try changing your tsconfig.json to this:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node"
    // rest of config...
  }
}

